# How to navigate multiple ctags matches in Vim?

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> in Vim to navigate using Ctags.
How do I navigate to alternate file if there are multiple matches?

Ex. `something.publish` in a codebase containing multiple occurrences of `publish`:

```
class Foo
  def publish
  end
end

class Bar
  def publish
  end
end
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`:tn[ext]` goes to the next tag, `:tp[revious]` goes to the previous one.  `:ts[elect]` gives you a list to choose from.

`:help tag-matchlist` for more fun and exciting things to try!

Answer (score 127):

Use `g]` instead of `C-]` to get the list of all matches.

You might want to read `:help g]`

Comment: How do you select a match from the list of matches displayed by control-] 
?

Comment: If I recall correctly, every match has a number, so you just type that number (e.g. 3) and hit Enter.

Answer (score 34):

*Adding the answer I was ultimately looking for in case it helps others:*

`g<C-]>` will jump to the tag if there's only one match and will present a list if there are multiple matches.

I've added this mapping to my .vimrc to make it do what I want by default:

`nnoremap <C-]> g<C-]>`

Comment: Very cool.. As, it happens in `vim` very frequently..I actually accidentally pressed this.. and was wondering how I can get that functionality again :)

Answer (score 1):

**`ltag`**

```
ltag the_tag_name
lopen
```

opens a location window with the tag matches.

This is specially powerful with regular expression tag searches:

```
ltag /tag_na
lopen
```

which will list all tags that contain the string `tag_na` (thus including `the_tag_name`).

You can then further search inside the location list, before hitting enter to jump to the tag.

To use it for the word under the cursor, you might want to define the map:

```
nnoremap <leader>l exec("ltag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

Then, if you are a tab maniac like me:

```
command! -nargs=1 Ltag silent ltag <args> | execute "normal \<C-o>" | tab lopen
```

will open a new tab with the location list and all the matches, instead of jumping to the tab directly:

```
:Ltag /my_struct
```