# vim tags: how to get <C-w><C-]> behave with tselect

Tags: vim, ctags

With the help of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078499/629530

I've added this in my ~/.vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-]> g<C-]>
```

That works well: `<C-]>` now shows the `tselect` output and I can choose the option I desire. But I also like to use `<C-w><C-]>` to open the tag result in a new split vim window. But that behaves with the old `tag` (`<C-]>`) behavior. I want that to show the `tselect` output as well. I tried this:

```
nnoremap <C-w><C-]> g<C-w><C-]>
```

and this:

```
nnoremap <C-w><C-]> <C-w>g<C-]>
```

But neither of those work like I want.

The fact is: is there a way to make `:tag`, `<C-]>`, etc. all behave by default with the `tselect` behavior? I would prefer that.

Thanks,

Comment: I always have to look at the help for these commands, but maybe it’s `<C-w>g]` ? Check the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#CTRL-W_g]), the <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> combination is what splits, then uses the under-cursor word as the tag to `:tselect` on. So your `.vimrc` should have:

```
nnoremap <C-w><C-]> <C-w>g]
```

Comment: Dang, I’m impressed I remembered that righ